# How to access an object that is inside two html forms using javascript?

Tags: javascript

why if this code works:

```
<form name="form1"><textarea class="xxlarge" id="add_url_desc" name="j_desc" onKeyDown="textCounter(document.form1.j_desc,'job_limit',150)" onKeyUp="textCounter(document.form1.j_desc,'job_limit',150)"></textarea>
```

why this one dont?:

```
<form name="general">
<form name="form1"><textarea class="xxlarge" id="add_url_desc" name="j_desc" onKeyDown="textCounter(document.general.form1.j_desc,'job_limit',150)" onKeyUp="textCounter(document.general.form1.j_desc,'job_limit',150)"></textarea>
</form>
```

Why i cant trigger the onKey action when one form is inside other one??? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML doesn't allow nested forms.

Comment: +1 - by my count you had two more characters in that answer than needed :)

Answer (score 1):

You just can't nest forms in HTML. It will never work right... not only will javascript break, the browser won't know how to handle the forms either. Sorry.